# Analysis of a continuous outcome for a treatment in a very small sample size (6 treatment, 5 controls) while adjusting for confounding variables

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, small-sample, confounding, case-control-study

I have to assess changes in a continuous outcome after a treatment, however, my sample size is very small (6 treatment, 5 controls). Also, I need to adjust for 4-5 confounding variables such as age, sex, BMI, etc. in my analysis. Please can you suggest appropriate methods for such a comparison.
My data looks something like this:

| Sample ID | treatment group | Age | sex | BMI | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 15 | F | 19 | 9.5% |
| 2 | 1 | 16.3 | M | 20 | 12% |

Comment: Sorry, but with just 11 data points, it will already be hard to meaningfully assess changes in the outcome (unless they are *blatant*, as in having all value in one group larger than in the other group), much less "adjust for" covariates. Bayesian methods might be a way forward, but even then, with such a small sample size, your results will be extremely sensitive to your priors.

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa! If I drop adjustment for covariates, would a simple comparison of treatment vs control groups by t-test or Fisher's exact test be sensible?

Comment: [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) assesses contingency tables, i.e., tables of discrete data, it is not appropriate here. A t test would be possible. With your small sample size, you could also run a permutation test, as in the introductory example in Good's textbook *Permutation, Parametric, and Bootstrap Tests of Hypotheses*.